# R/tuneR: Generating sound from different location

Tags: r, audio, simulation, tuner

I want to simulate the sound in a 2D area, for example, in a metal rod. Let's consider that I have two acoustic recorders recording this sound from different spots. I discovered two packages in R, namely tuneR and Seewave, that can be used to create a sound. Is there a way to generate a sound similar to the image below? I am still in the process of learning about these packages, so I am not sure if they can fulfill my requirements. If you know of other ways in R, your guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

I understand that it depends on the velocity of sound in the metal and other parameters. I just want to create a simple sound from two different locations, and then I can adjust it accordingly.